# How to execute methods that are really time consuming? asp.net (cron)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cron

I have a small web application for me and a couple of friends. The main task for this application is to analyse data for us. Large amount of data. 
The data is analysed during night, and available for us in the morning.

I guess that the total amount of time for the download might be around 15 minutes, and the total amount of time for the analysis is arournd 15 minutes.

Currently, both the download and analysis is splited so that everytime I execute a specific page on my web application, the server downloads 10 files and stores it in my database. The same is done with the analysis.

But as amount of data increase, there is a risk that the page timeout and data is being corrupted, files not downloaded etc.

Is there a way to make a asp.net file, execute for a longer time. Like running in the background on the server doing everything once, until the download is finished, and later until the analysis is finished?

So there is 2 things I wonder:
1. I dont have full access to the server, So I would like to, by accessing a webpage, execute another file, that continues to run in the background. So that I dont have the problem with a webpage that times out. Is it called asynchronous execution?
2. How Do i design/create a file that doesnt timeout. It runs more lika a program on a computer. Until it is finished..

I hope that I have been clear with my questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make a asp.net file, execute for a longer time

Don't do it, it is extremely bad idea as Phil Haack explains in [`this blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx). Such long tasks shouldn't be done in ASP.NET but offloaded to some other service (For example a Windows Service or Console application scheduled to run at regular intervals)

Comment: Thanks. I kind of knew that, but i dont know any other option for me. With asp.net-file, I actually mean any type of file that can be used on a windows server (created by the MS visual studio). I dont have any other access to the server than ftp, so the only thing I can do is to some kind of file, using MSVS, and execute it by using a asp.net file.

Comment: If it is possible, I would like to use an ordinare .aspx file, as "trigger", executing the download method, or analysis method. But the aspx file should not wait for it. Just start it, and then leave it running.. Possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible -> spawn a new thread and execute the code inside (`new Thread(() => { /** your code comes here **/ }).Start();`). Recommended: TOTALLY NOT! But why not: read the blog post linked in my answer, it already covers the pitfalls in details.

Comment: Thank you. I think that I will continue with aspx files that are doing everything, but find a way to divide it into smaller, and less time consuming parts.